# Sonarsource Community Edition License

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We want to build a commercial product using SonarSource Community Edition which we deployed on our own servers, I am not able to find relevant information regarding its licensing faqs, can we create the product using it and sell it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SonarQube Community Edition is licensed under the GNU Lesser GPL License v3, as you can read on the [License page on sonarqube.org](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/license/).

If you want to know what you can legally do with this LGPL v3 license, you can chek the following page: https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-lesser-general-public-license-v3-(lgpl-3)

Comment: The Licensing terms under LGPL is pretty hard to decipher, also cant afford to hire a lawyer :(, can you please tell me in simple words whether I can use SonaSource Comm Edition, host on our server, use its API and create product which can be licensed? What all things I need to take care of?

Comment: Hi Fabrice, Any thoughts on my last comment?